# Segmentation Fault (core dumped) in C in Delete() function

Tags: c, linked-list, runtime-error, nodes

i am writing a Dictionary using linked list in C, and all my functions work except my delete function, which is shown below along with all other necessary code. Every time i try to run my program as soon as it reaches a line in which it must delete a node, it gives me the error: Segmentation Fault (core dumped) which means it has something to do with the memory allocation or a null pointer i think. I know that the rest of my code works. All and any help is appreciated! :)

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<assert.h>
#include"Dictionary.h"

// NodeObj
typedef struct NodeObj{
    char* key;
    char* value;
    struct NodeObj* next;
} NodeObj;

// Node
typedef NodeObj* Node;

// newNode()
// constructor of the Node type
Node newNode(char* key, char* value)
{
    Node N = malloc(sizeof(NodeObj));
    assert(N!=NULL);
    //  if(key!=NULL && value!=NULL){
    N->key = key;
    N->value = value;
    N->next = NULL;
    //  }
    return(N);
}

// DictionaryObj
typedef struct DictionaryObj{
    Node head;
    int numItems;
} DictionaryObj;

// newDictionary()
// constructor for the Dictionary type
Dictionary newDictionary(void){
    Dictionary D = malloc(sizeof(DictionaryObj));
    assert(D!=NULL);
    D->head = NULL;
    D->numItems = 0;
    return D;
}

Node findKey(Dictionary D, char*key){
    Node N;
    N = D->head;
    while(N != NULL){
        if(strcmp(N->key,key)==0){
            return N;
        }
        N = N->next;
    }
    return NULL;
}

char* lookup(Dictionary D, char* k){
    if(findKey(D, k)==NULL){
        return NULL;
    }else{
        Node N;
        N = findKey(D, k);
        return N->value;
    }
}

void delete(Dictionary D, char* k)
{
    if(lookup(D,k) == NULL){
        fprintf(stderr,
                "KeyNotFoundException: Cannot delete non-existent key\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    int check = strcmp(D->head->key, k);
    if(check == 1){
        D->head = D->head->next;
        return;
    }
    Node cur;
    Node prev;
    cur = D->head;
    prev = NULL;

    while( cur != NULL){
        int ret1;
        ret1 = strcmp(cur->key, k);
        while( ret1 == 0){
            prev = cur;
            cur = cur->next;
        }
    }
    prev->next = cur->next;
    D->numItems--;
}
```

Comment: When you run this under a debugger, where does the crash seem to stem? And you didn't provide `Dictionary.h`, which is important. Regardless, my crystal ball tells me this: `N->value = value;` is up to no good. I believe the string your passing for the value isn't dynamically allocated on the caller side. Rather, I believe it likely a local automatic char buffer that is destroyed and leaving a dictionary full of dangling pointers for values.

Comment: Dictionary.h just defines the functions listed here and says what they do in the comments. the crash seems to stem from function delete(), possibly in the strcmp() areas

Comment: 1. Where are key+value stored? (I think you should make a copy) 2. You should not compare strcmp's result with 1 (if(check == 1)) but either is 0 or is not.

Comment: i have another insert() not shown that uses all of the functions listed except for delete() and it works fine, so i don't think there is a problem with that code.. also thanks firda i changed the strcmp comparison from checking for 1 to 0

Comment: Also please, *please*, unless it is an opaque library "handle" type or a function pointer typedef, *please* don't bury pointers in typedef aliases. It does *nothing* for clarity and actually makes the code *harder* to read. (props to not casting malloc, btw).

Comment: insert() can work even with 'strings' on the stack, but when you leave that code, those pointers gets invalid (but I think that it would crash in lookup). So rather again, where are all those strings for key+value stored? Global array?

Comment: sorry about that, i'm very new to C programming and i'm sure it looks really messy :( i actually am attempting to translate my working Dictionary from java to C.
the key,value strings are stored inside the Nodes in the linked list i've created

Comment: no, there are pointers in your Node, not the data itself - your new Node should make a copy.

Comment: BTW: Can you use STL string? Is that a homework?

Comment: Start a debugger. Step through the function. Note the values of the variables.

Comment: @firda C doesn't have any STL, so I'm going unlikely on using STL strings.

Comment: @WhozCraig: yes, thx, already noticed we are not in C++ but pure C.

Answer (score 0):

The `NodeObject` should store copy of the string and care for deleting it:

```
typedef struct Node Node;
struct Node {
    Node *next;
    char *key, *value;
};

Node* newNode(char* key, char* value) {
    assert(key && value);
    Node* node = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    assert(node);
    node->next = NULL;
    node->key = strdup(key);
    node->value = strdup(value);
}
void delNode(Node* node) {
    free(node->key);
    free(node->value);
}
```

Consider using the original code (without that `strdup`) in this scenairo:

```
Node* prepare() {
    char key_buf[20]; strcpy(key_buf, "mykey");
    char val_buf[20]; strcpy(val_buf, "myval");
    return newNode(key_buf, val_buf);
}
void examine(Node* node) {
   printf("Node key=%s value=%s\n", node->key, node->value);
}
int main() {
    examine(prepare());
}
```

the above code would crash because Node would have pointers to stack (in your case without that `strdup`), but key_buf+val_buf were only valid inside prepare() (garbage outside and therefore inside examine() - node->key points to random data).